# How to free TMessage

Tags: delphi, messaging

I'm using Delphi 10.2, coding for mobile but testing on Windows. I'm getting an 'Invalid pointer operation' error when trying to delete the message (using either Free or DisposeOf) in the following code:

```
procedure TViewmodelAuthentication.HandleSignUp;
var
    lTarget: TFrameSetupRecord;
    lMsg: TMessage;
begin
    lTarget.Frame := ftSignUp;
    lTarget.Direction := TTabTransitionDirection.Normal;
    lMsg := TGoToMessage<TFrameSetupRecord>.Create(lTarget);
    TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(self, lMsg);
    lMsg.DisposeOf;  //Error: Invalid pointer operation
end;
```

I notice that the message is not deleted in this Embarcadero code example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MessageManager: TMessageManager;
  Message: TMessage;
begin
  MessageManager := TMessageManager.DefaultManager;
  Message := TMessage<UnicodeString>.Create(Edit1.Text);
  MessageManager.SendMessage(Sender, Message, True);
end;
```

But the docs on TMessage seem to say the message should be deleted:

> However, when you create a TMessage with an object as value, TMessage
>   does not take ownership of the object; you must delete the object
>   yourself, and ensure that the message has been deleted first.

How should I delete the message?

Thanks

Comment: Don't try to free the `TMessage` itself at all.  The `MessageManager` takes ownership of it and will free it for you. The doc you quoted is not talking about freeing the `TMessage` itself, but rather freeing an object that you decide to put *inside* the `TMessage`. That object, you have to free yourself, AFTER the `TMessage` is no longer holding a reference to it. This is not an issue under platforms that use ARC for object lifetime management (iOS and Android, but not Windows). Note that object ARC will be removed in RAD Studio 10.4.x, so you will have to free unowned objects manually again.

Comment: To let `TMessage` take ownership of an object that you put inside a message, use [`TObjectMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TObjectMessage), as the [`TMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessage) documentation says to.

Comment: If I understand, I don't have to free the TMessage, on any platform or under 10.4.x. I made the object in the TMessage a record to try and avoid this ownership issue. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @DavidU You only need to free TMessage if you call SendMessage with the 3rd parameter set to False. As for what the documentation state, it refers to lTarget, in your example.

Comment: @Remy I find that rule change absolutely hilarious, back when I first learned that object ARC was supported, I laughed and told myself I'd still care to write my code to free them anyway just as always. Looks like I made a smart choice!

Answer (score -1):

You don't delete a TMessage. It is a record, not an object or a pointer. A TMessage is treated the same way by the compiler ans an Integer or Byte - a chunk of memory that is moved around and replicated as needed.
It is not an address or reference. What the docs are telling you is that if the TMessage contains a reference to a different, separate, object, you are responsible for ensuring it is freed.

Comment: A TMessage, as in System.Messaging.TMessage, is an object, not a record. That is the type being referenced here, not Winapi.Messages.TMessage.